# base-R: dataframe’s with a mix of scalar and non-scalar entries

Tags: r, dataframe

I am building a dataframe with 1 column of range values, 2 columns of regular 1-dim scalars:

desired dataframe:

```
        range       mean       sd
1     c(2, 10)      5.5       11.11
2     c(3, 5)       7.88      12.01
3     c(4, 12)      8.10      13.10 
4     c(2, 22)     18.10       3.10
```

The code to build the df row by row is straightforward:

```
cols = list(list(c(2,10), c(3,5), c(4,12), c(2,22)), 
            c(5.5, 7.88, 8.10, 18.10), 
            c(11.11, 12.01, 13.10, 3.10))   # data is as a list of the column values
df = data.frame()
for (in in 1:4) {  # iter over rows
   row = list()
   for (j in 1:3) {   # iter over cols
      row[[j]] = cols[[j]][[i]]
   }
   df = rbind(df, row)
}
```

•  **My problem is that the rbind fails because cols[[1]][[i]] is of type `range`, which has dim=2 (not a scalar).** The code is fine if you use a scalar type for column 1.

•  I understand that the *idea of df* is to be a tabular structure of scalars.

•  However, suppose I want to have the structure above, because then I can reference an ij^th entry and get the full object out (usually a scalar but for column 1, I can get a range object conveniently).

•  How to do this while keeping the thing as a dataframe?  Is something like #2 below possible? (Or, any better/simpler solutions!)

1. One method is to convert every non-scalar entry to a string:  `toString( cols[[j]][[i]] )`

   - The downside is if you want to use lose all semantic info of the object
2. I really envision having a `toString()-transformer` which gets **automagically** called on the non-scalar entries (say, we specify this transformer to be called for any entry of column 1) whenever the dataframe is being used in a context required for all-scalar entries (ie, printing via built-in R printing).
   Here, **automagically** just means I do a bunch of annoying work up-front but then the usage-code comes out very neat  :D

EDIT: an example of an automagic way (code smell warning) would be say JavaScript object’s .get() accessor — which you can override and wrap with a `toString(NextMethod)` transformer , where `NextMethod` is the super() call from R::s3

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You could keep it a list and still reference ijth entry...

Comment: @d.b very true. I need to keep it simple. thanks

Comment: `mapply(function(x, i) x[i], cols, list(1:4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do: define a class with nice `format`, `print`, `as.data.frame` and `[` methods that sits nicely inside a data frame and acts just as you would expect:

```r
range <- function(lower, upper) {
  structure(list(lower = lower, upper = upper), class = "range")
}

`[.range` <- function(obj, n) range(obj$lower[n], obj$upper[n])

length.range <- function(obj) length(obj$lower)

as.data.frame.range <- function(obj, ...) {
   structure( list(range = obj), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = seq_along(obj$lower)
             )
}

as.character.range <- function(obj) {
   paste0("c(", obj$lower, ", ", obj$upper, ")")
}

format.range <- function(obj, ...) as.character(obj)

print.range <- function(obj) print(as.character(obj), quote = FALSE)
```

Which looks and behaves like this:

```
df <- data.frame(range = range(1:10, 11:20), 
                 letters = LETTERS[1:10], 
                 numbers = 101:110)
df
#>        range letters numbers
#> 1   c(1, 11)       A     101
#> 2   c(2, 12)       B     102
#> 3   c(3, 13)       C     103
#> 4   c(4, 14)       D     104
#> 5   c(5, 15)       E     105
#> 6   c(6, 16)       F     106
#> 7   c(7, 17)       G     107
#> 8   c(8, 18)       H     108
#> 9   c(9, 19)       I     109
#> 10 c(10, 20)       J     110

df[, 1]
#>  [1] c(1, 11)  c(2, 12)  c(3, 13)  c(4, 14)  c(5, 15)  c(6, 16)  c(7, 17) 
#>  [8] c(8, 18)  c(9, 19)  c(10, 20)

df$range[1]
#> [1] c(1, 11)

df$range[1]$lower
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The other suggested solutions (tibble and keeping it simple: store a reference copy as a list or matrix-used-for-display) are very nice too. Be sure to check them out (and upvote them too).  This one, however, really gets the idea across on how to do something like this from raw, if wanted to. So, I think it is a great instructive example as well. Thanks for your kind answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want, but simpler. You can include a matrix as a column in a data frame but you have to add it after the data frame is constructed:

```
range <- rbind(c(2,10), c(3,5), c(4,12), c(2,22))
cols <- data.frame(mean=c(5.5, 7.88, 8.10, 18.10),
         sd=c(11.11, 12.01, 13.10, 3.10))   
cols$range <- range
str(cols)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ mean : num  5.5 7.88 8.1 18.1
#  $ sd   : num  11.1 12 13.1 3.1
#  $ range: num [1:4, 1:2] 2 3 4 2 10 5 12 22
```

You can use `cols <- cols[, c(3, 1, 2)]` if you want the matrix as the first column

Comment: This is also a nice clean solution. I think this method is fine. What I was shooting for is way too complex and bloated. I like this too. Data synchronization isn’t an issue if you are aware of when it gets updated. I’ll see if anything else pops up, but this is a nice way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's one solution very close to what you seem to be looking for, using tibbles.

```
> cols = list(list(c(2,10), c(3,5), c(4,12), c(2,22)), 
+             c(5.5, 7.88, 8.10, 18.10), 
+             c(11.11, 12.01, 13.10, 3.10))
> (tb <- tibble(range = cols[[1]], mean = cols[[2]], sd = cols[[3]]))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  range      mean    sd
  <list>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 <dbl [2]>  5.5   11.1
2 <dbl [2]>  7.88  12.0
3 <dbl [2]>  8.1   13.1
4 <dbl [2]> 18.1    3.1
> (df <- as.data.frame(tb))
  range  mean    sd
1 2, 10  5.50 11.11
2  3, 5  7.88 12.01
3 4, 12  8.10 13.10
4 2, 22 18.10  3.10
```

The dataframe df has a structure similar to what you're looking for, for instance

```
df$range[1]
[[1]]
[1]  2 10
```

gives you a list with 2 elements, list(2, 10), but not c(2, 10) as you intended. Functionally however this should allow you to treat the data as it was your intention initially.

However I haven't managed to skip the tibble step to build that dataframe!

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I think the author of tidyr has set out to tackle a lot of implicit problems — it seems his tibble is itself a general-purpose solution that can address this problem too.  Great, thanks for kind suggestion.